# Is there a delay on using an android test account?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-service, in-app-billing

I have followed the steps for android in app purchasing pretty much down to a t.

I have exported my signed app,

I make a request bundle of ITEM_ID - "sword"

I upload the apk and create the in app purchasing entry with item id "sword" and I then install my signed apk onto my second phone - which is assigned to my google test account.

All i get is RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR which according to :

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

Says I have made one of the following mistakes :

1/manifest is wrong - my manifest definietly requested the billing
2/application is not properly signed - I am installing the signed apk which I uploaded to the android developer console
3/Missing bundle keys or unrecognized request type - my bundle looks as follows:

```
request.putString("BILLING_REQUEST", method);
request.putInt("API_VERSION", 1);
Log.e("sc2","package name is :"+mContext.getPackageName());

request.putString("PACKAGE_NAME", mContext.getPackageName());
```

followed by :

```
   request.putString("ITEM_ID", itemId);
        try {
            Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);

            //The RESPONSE_CODE key provides you with the status of the request
            Integer responseCodeIndex   = (Integer) response.get("RESPONSE_CODE");
            //The PURCHASE_INTENT key provides you with a PendingIntent, which you can use to launch the checkout UI
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = (PendingIntent) response.get("PURCHASE_INTENT");
            //The REQUEST_ID key provides you with a unique request identifier for the request
            Long requestIndentifier     = (Long) response.get("REQUEST_ID");
            Log.i(TAG, "current request is:" + requestIndentifier);
            C.ResponseCode responseCode = C.ResponseCode.valueOf(responseCodeIndex);
            Log.i(TAG, "REQUEST_PURCHASE Sync Response code: "+responseCode.toString());

            startBuyPageActivity(pendingIntent, new Intent(), activityContext);
```

where itemId = "sword"

....I have exhausted every single shred of effort on this problem - and am tempted just to dump androids in app billing altogether inless some hero can perhaps capture what is going wrong here.

All the standard product ID's for testing like android.test.purchase etc work perfectly.

Comment: Most Google APIs have a delay. Try tomorrow.

Comment: really!? Where does it say that?

Comment: My real life with Android experience says that :)

Comment: Ok - happily it has now started working - however the option for paying with a fake VISA isnt there, so how do I run through the purchasing part of that if the fake visa is not an option?! Do I actually have to pay?

Comment: You have to pay. There's no pretend money in the system. The only developer allowance they provide is that you can use in-app payments before the app is published. You can set the price to the minimum (the users won't notice, as there are none), and you can cancel and refund your test orders.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the answer was - yes - indeed. It was simply a delay between me adding my google test account and it actually being recognised as such :@! Google should have a warning about this - in-app billing is a complete nightmare to code!